# Static Instance releasing properties prematurely with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have a static instance variable that is being used throughout my application.  It has properties.  These properties are used through my application and seem to work pretty well.  However, sometimes the properties are released prematurely.  What is odd is that the object that is pulling these properties keeps some and releases others.  What would be a good way to insure that the properties of my object are not released prematurely.

**Edit:** It turns out that the issue was not premature releasing at all.  It was a conversion issue.  Thanks all for help.

```
@interface Game : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject     *gameObject;
//@property (nonatomic, strong) Concept     *concept; // Will need to add Concept Object to GameObject once it's wrapper is done
@property (nonatomic, strong) User         *initialPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) User         *invitedPlayer;         
@property (nonatomic, strong) User         *lastPlayedPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate       *lastPlayedDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate       *timeOutDate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int           timerTicks;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int           currentRoundNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) User          *winnerPlayer;         
@property (nonatomic, assign) int           initialPlayerPoints;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int           invitedPlayerPoints;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int           currentPlayerPoints;
@property (nonatomic, assign) GameStatus    status;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int           initialPlayerTimeouts;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int           invitedPlayerTimeouts;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL          isInitialPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *rounds;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly)     Round *currentRound;

+(void)getActiveUserGameObjects:(PFUser *)user target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;
+(void)getYourTurnGameObjects:(PFUser *)user target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;
+(void)getTheirTurnGameObjects:(PFUser *)user target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;
+(void)getGameObjects:(PFUser *)user yourTurn:(id)yourTurn target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;

+(Game*)currentGame;
+(void)setCurrentGame:(Game*)currentGame;

..

//.m @implementation   
..

static Game *sharedInstance = nil;
..


+(Game*)currentGame
{
    return sharedInstance;
}

+(void)setCurrentGame:(Game*)currentGame
{
    sharedInstance = currentGame;
}


...

#pragma mark - Player Setters and Getters

-(void)setInvitedPlayer:(User *)invitedPlayer
{
    if (nil != invitedPlayer.userObject)
    {
        [self.gameObject setObject:invitedPlayer.userObject forKey:GAME_INVITED_PLAYER];
    }
}

-(User*)invitedPlayer
{
    NSObject *value = [self.gameObject objectForKey:GAME_INVITED_PLAYER];
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[PFUser class]])
    {
        return [User userFromPFUser:(PFUser*)value];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: What momory attributes do you use for your properties?

Comment: Post your header, no one can determine how you have defined the properties from what you posted.

Comment: Try testing your app with the Zombies instrument. That will give you the full retain/release history of an object that is begin released too many times.

Comment: Header is posted.  Thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be a good way to insure that the properties of my object are not released prematurely.

Holding onto them by maintaining a strong reference. It is extremely unlikely that ARC is randomly releasing your data. Much more likely is that you are letting go of it when you don't mean to.

The first place I'd look is at your use of `setCurrentGame:`, making sure that you're not accidentally working on different `Game` objects at the same time in different parts of the program. First, make sure t

Your `+get...` methods are awkwardly named (a `get` prefix means a very specific thing in ObjC, and it's not what you're doing here). Havings class methods that take targets and actions like this seems a likely place to have trouble. It makes me wonder what's going on inside there.

Your conversion between two kinds of `User` objects is a little suspicious, and I'd make sure you're not accidentally dropping User or PFUser objects when you don't mean to.

Generally speaking, though, this question is over-vague. Are you winding up with dangling strong pointers? Are your strong pointers seeming to become `nil`? Is your game object itself becoming `nil`? How do you know when things are being "released?" Or do you mean that they're deallocating? Have you put a breakpoint in `dealloc` to see who had the last reference to the object?

Comment: There is no dealloc for the object.  You're right about the +get.. User object from PFUser is for the purposes of having a wrapper around a data object that might get switched out with a different SDK or service at a later time.  You're also right that's it's over vague.  The getters are returning an int from a data object (PFObject).  When I return an intValue in my getter as a GameStatus enum, the variable becomes (null).

Comment: You can always add a `dealloc` so you can log or breakpoint on it. What variable becomes "null?" intValue can't be null. And do you mean it "becomes" null while calling intValue (it was not null before, and then is null)? Or do you mean something else? I suspect there is a lot more digging you need to do in order to establish exactly what is happening when.

Comment: Actually I edited the question to note that the issue was resolved.  It turns out that I made a dumb mistake and was trying to return an intValue of an object that wasn't an NSNumber.  The design of the class is poor and going in post creation and debugging is trouble.  I appreciate your help.  Thanks for the dealloc tip.  I'm very new to ARC.

Comment: One other quick question Rob.  I see you've written a book.  I'm a bit of a hacker, I've been programming for 20 years.  New to Mac, but I would like to become thoroughly proficient.  My current practice of self-teaching, building, experimenting, reading, is not enough.  What do you suggest to get thoroughly proficient?

Comment: Make sure to read the Programming Guides that Apple writes, and their introductory materials. These are often more important than the class references. Spend time getting comfortable with the Cocoa patterns. Good design and naming is critical in Cocoa. My book assumes you understand Cocoa development already, but the second section is devoted to the common patterns. You may also find this one useful: http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-iOS-Development-Exploring-SDK/dp/1430236051. I've written about learning Cocoa from other backgrounds here: http://robnapier.net/blog/learning-cocoa-2-467

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your properties are (retain) type (same as strong, I think), and keep an instance refereed to in the app delegate (so that ARC sees the reference as valid for the entire execution of your program).

Comment: ARC does allow retain as a property attribute. It's a synonym for strong.

Comment: That's right, but it doesn't allow a retain on an int since it's not an object.

Comment: True, but was there a retained int here?

Comment: @Adam, you should not fetch data from your app delegate. It is not your model. You can create the data in your app delegate and pass it to your controllers as you create them, or you can store your model in a singleton. But almost nothing should talk directly to the app delegate except the UIApplication itself.